# show that a function is continuous at a given interval?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Show that $f(x)= 1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is continuous on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Show how I work with such a question please. I have watched many youtube videos, but I can't seem to get the idea.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Your question is a bit vague.  You have not explained what definitions you are allowed to use or what properties of continuous functions you are allowed to assume, so the reader does not know whether you want to prove continuity from the definition or by showing that $f$ is the composition of continuous functions.  Therefore, that information should be included in your question.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=1-x^2$ and

$h(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

$h$ is continuous at $\color{red}{[0,+\infty)}$.

$g$ is continuous at $[-1,1]$ and
$g([-1,1])\subset \color{red}{[0,+\infty)}$

since $\forall x\in[-1,1] \;\; 1-x^2\ge 0$

thus
$$ f=h(g) \text{ is continuous at } [-1,1].$$

Comment: thank you so much. its working now